# Making vertex paints visible in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, texturing

Using Blender 2.78.

When working, I'll often flip between edit mode and vertex paint mode, painting as I go. How do I go about seeing **non-baked** vertex paints on my mesh when in edit mode?

I am **not** asking how to apply vertex paints or use vertex paint mode

I have done this before **without baking the textures first**

I have done this before **without use of nodes** and would prefer that a solution either doesn't use nodes, or if it does, has a quick explanation of nodes for dummies.

Thanks!

Comment: In 2.8 there is a vertex button in the shading menu (little triangle next to the 3 little ball in the right upper corner). In 2.7x if you in Blender Render, then you can see it in texture view even if you have texture.

Comment: Thank you!

It didn't work at first, but it turned out I had a mirror modifier on without realizing. After applying the modifier, texture view worked perfectly. Thank you!